# Where is simba package in R 4.1.3

Tags: r, package, simba

I am using R 4.1.3 and I am not able to find the package simba anymore.

> `library(simba)`

> `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘simba’:
> package ‘simba’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it

It is not present anymore in install packages.
Has it been changed for a new package?

Comment: When switching between minor (but not patch levels) of R such as 4.0 to 4.1, it's generally recommended (sometimes required) to reinstall many packages. Unfortunately, the CRAN maintainers are being a bit harsh by removing it based on a [NOTE](https://cran-archive.r-project.org/web/checks/2021/2021-10-20_check_results_simba.html). You can try to install it via `remotes::install_github("cran/simba")`, not sure if it'll work. (Note: the package has not changed in 10 years. Sometimes that means uber-stable, sometimes it means something else. I don't know, I don't use it.)

Comment: thanks for your help. many packages have disappeared. I really need them.

Answer (score 0):

@ https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simba/index.html I found that:

Package ‘simba’ was removed from the CRAN repository.

Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.

Archived on 2021-10-20 as check problems were not corrected in time.

A summary of the most recent check results can be obtained from the check results archive.

Please use the canonical form https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=simba to link to this page.